# What issue can make very short temperature spikes to appear?

Tags: prusa-i3, temperature, e3d-revo

I have issues with momentarily temperature spikes, but only above 250 °C. At and below 250 °C it's pretty solid.

I'm using Prusa MK3s+ with a E3D Revo upgrade.

I suspected connector issues as described in [Random hot-end temperature spikes](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/16154/20803) but in my case, the reported temperature spikes up, then compensates down - exactly opposite to what Space Faring Or Bust reported. Also, my issue happens only at specific temperatures. Connectors on both ends of a cable look good. I don't recall it happening earlier, on my old V6 hotend.

A side question is, are these even real? Or just a read error or a display artifact?

I cut the connector off and re-crimped it, but it didn't help, it looks exactly as it did before.

[image: Screenshot of Octoprint's temperature graph showing spikes for the hotend]

Comment: Faulty sensor? Is your firmware using MPC or PID for nozzle temperature control? Is it (auto) tuned?

Comment: @BobOrtiz PID and it was tuned. I ordered new heater (revo uses heaters with built-in sensors) so I'll be able to try different one in a week or so.

Comment: Maybe far fetched and would probably give more issues but faulty power supply and power spikes?

Comment: I'd love to know how to test that. I don't have spares. It might make sense as it only happens with higher power consumption.